# Why does princomp in R stats package use population sd if data is supplied but sample sd if covariance matrix is supplied?

Tags: r, pca

In `princomp` of the R `stats` package, I noticed that the "scale" of the output varies based on whether the raw data or the covariance matrix is supplied. The scalings should be equivalent to the standard deviation of the variable, but I noticed that if the data itself is supplied, the population standard deviation (denominator n) is used whereas if the covariance matrix is supplied, then the sample standard deviation (denominator n-1) is used. I was wondering why this is the case?

```r
data("iris")

sd_pop<- function(x){
  sqrt(sum((x-mean(x))^2)/length(x))
  } #Population sd formula

iris<- iris[,-length(iris)] #drop species column

pca_data<- princomp(iris, cor=TRUE) #with data
pca_cov<- princomp(covmat=cov(iris), cor=TRUE) #with covariance matrix

# When using data scale is population sd
pca_data$scale - sapply(iris, sd)
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#> -0.002764836 -0.001455317 -0.005894167 -0.002545041
pca_data$scale - sapply(iris, sd_pop)
#>  Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width  Petal.Length   Petal.Width 
#>  0.000000e+00 -3.330669e-16  2.220446e-16  2.220446e-16

# When using covariance scale is sample sd
pca_cov$scale - sapply(iris, sd)
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#>            0            0            0            0
pca_cov$scale - sapply(iris, sd_pop)
#> Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#>  0.002764836  0.001455317  0.005894167  0.002545041
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't get it: in computing `pca_cov` you *explicitly* request the $1/(n-1)$ version of covariance because that's what `cov` computes.  This has nothing to do with `princomp`!

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the insight. I still do think it has a bit to do with `princomp` though because for the same dataset you will get a slightly different answer if you choose to perform the PCA directly on the data versus if you use the `covmat` argument. I guess more so it's interesting that `princomp` uses the population standard deviation if the data is supplied since `sd`, `var`, and `cov` in R all use the sample formula.

Comment: What happens when you use the `covmat` argument with a covariance matrix computed with the $1/n$ factor instead? ;-)  BTW, if this truly concerns you, look into `prcomp` -- but I suspect you're asking primarily out of curiosity rather than any worry about the (inconsequential) differences in results.

Comment: Thanks, yeah mainly asking out of curiosity. Once you pointed out the cov uses n-1 that made sense, and I realize if I put a covariance matrix computed with n as the denominator it'd come out the same, but that's just not usually how the default stats functions in R calculate things.

Comment: The very first thing to know about `R` is that it isn't consistent :-).